# YUI DataTable - multiple columns filtering

Tags: datatable, yui, filtering

I know, that it is possible to filter dataTable Control on client as it is shown in this exaple:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_localfilter.html

Is it also possible to filter more columns? I'd like to have 2 textfields, and when I type sth to the first one, DataTable would filter according to the 'areacode' (from the example) and when I type sth to the second one, DataTable would filter according to the 'state'.

Is this possible somehow? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to modify the existing example would be to build a request string that contains the information for each text box.  For example (column1=a&colum2=b), modify the doBeforeCallback to split the request and do the filtering for each column.